# Where does Chainlink get its deviation threshold from?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, oracles, chainlink

I understand Chainlink updates either every hour or once the price moves beyond a deviation threshold (often 0.5% or 1%).
But where does Chainlink check for this deviation?

Answer (score 0):

The deviation is defined for each aggregator. And the nodes check the deviation of the current price vs the last price stored on-chain before coming to a decision as to whether an update is needed